# Is there a way to temporarily enlarge the mouse pointer like Apple's "Shake to find" does?

Tags: mouse, cursor

I'm aware of Apple's "Shake to find" feature, which enlarges the pointer (too briefly for me), and I occasionally use it.

I'm also aware of (increasingly unstable and out-of-date) third-party programs like "Mouse Locator" and Mouseposé, both of which suffer from lack of upgrades to keep up with Mac OS versions.

I'm looking for a way to trigger the temporary big cursor effect of "Shake to find" without shaking the mouse - as I want to keep the cursor near the thing I want to highlight.

Comment: "too briefly'... ermm... just keep it moving very slightly, it stays **big**. The behaviour has [improved/got more twitchy] in recent OSes.

Comment: Violently?  Something's wrong with your mouse, mate.

Comment: Can you clarify why you would want to do this? The point of the shake to find enlarging is normally to find it if you lost it, or reveal it if it has become hidden. You say that shake to find is a problem because it moves the cursor away from the thing you want to highlight--which implies that you already know where your cursor is. So what is the enlargement for? This will help me give you a better answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Yes: for me, "too briefly": It grows the cursor only while the mouse is actively "scrubbing," and returns to normal size within a tiny fraction of a second unless vigorous motion is maintained. If I start moving it at a "normal" pace after shaking, it almost instantly returns to normal size. I would guess in less than 0.1s.

Comment: @Allan: Yes, fairly violently. Thank you for your concern, but my mouse works just fine: it is capable of fine, delicate movements (as needed for my design work) as well as rapid displacements. "Shake to find" requires significant, constant movement in a very, very (~0.1s) short timeframe. "Violent" about describes it. Think "vigorously scrubbing" and you're about right.

Comment: @spacetyper I want to be able to highlight something at a particular place on screen during screen-sharing sessions with coworkers by hovering over it and "pulsing" the cursor. I don't want to move my cursor away from the very thing I'm trying to highlight, which is what's required with the constant, vigorous "scrubbing" required by "Shake to find."

Answer (score 4):

There is way to increase the size of your cursor, but it will stay that size until you change it again. Maybe making the cursor a little bigger will help?

Go to System Preferences and click Accessibility. Then on the left click on Display. Click on the subsection called "Cursor", then use the slider to set the cursor size. You can also turn off the feature where your cursor expands when you shake it by unchecking the box.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of this. I want to be able to momentarily increase the size of the cursor while leaving it in place, not having to shake the mouse … ahem … "violently" :-).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking in the wronn direction. The "Shake to Find" feature is used when you cannot find your mouse pointer. It is not intended to be used when you can locate the mouse pointer, but want to make others aware of its location.

In the comments you wrote that you specifically want this feature for making others aware of your mouse pointer location when screen sharing and similar. There's no way of making that feature do what you want.

Luckily, multiple utility apps exist for precisely this purpose:

You can go to the App Store and buy "Cursor Pro" by IXEAU UG, which works as a mouse pointer highlighter and magnifier when pressing a hot key.

Another alternative is the app "[Mouseposé](https://boinx.com/mousepose/)" from Boinx Software, which adds a spot light to your mouse pointer. It can also do other stuff such as adding an animation when you click the mouse. I haven't had any issues with stability with this program in its latest version.

A cheaper alternative is "[myPoint Light S](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mypoint-light-s/id518658487?mt=12)" from Code Race on the App Store, which allows you to add a visual effect to the mouse pointer by pressing a hot key.

Another alternative is the free program "[Highlighter](https://download.cnet.com/Highlighter/3000-2193_4-177023.html)" which permanently adds a ring around your mouse pointer.

Another free program is "[Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com/index.html)" from 2point5fish, which allows you to trigger a sniper like graphics with a hot key. This app doesn't seem to be updated anymore, though - so even though it is free, it might not be worth the extra effort.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not "looking in the wrong direction." I'm looking for a way to take advantage of an obviously built-in behavior, rather than adding third party software to my system. I have used Mouseposé while recording videos to highlight the mouse location. Most mouse locators are silly toys.

Comment: Well, you have that opinion and that's okay... but as there's no way to make the functionality built for use case A to work with use case B the way you want, you really want one of those "silly toys"...