# Temporarily show location of mouse pointer (without having to move the mouse)?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, magic-trackpad, cursor

I have to work with both Windows 10 and MacOS (Big Sur) daily. I have the "Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key" option enabled in Windows. This option is extremely helpful when locating the mouse cursor since it doesn't necessitate having to move the mouse; simply tapping the CTRL key causes radiating circles to briefly appear around the cursor.

I've been unsuccessful in finding a similar feature for MacOS. [Mouse Pointer Locator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/189006/mouse-pointer-locator) and
[Is there a way to temporarily enlarge the mouse pointer like Apple's "Shake to find" does?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331645/is-there-a-way-to-temporarily-enlarge-the-mouse-pointer-like-apples-shake-to-f) represent similar requests; the recommended solutions, however, don't seem to provide the feature I describe.

MacOS's built-in 'Shake mouse pointer to locate' (and the Magic Trackpad equivalent) is too disruptive. And many of the suggested apps require toggling into a mode to make the mouse cursor look differently and then toggling out of that mode to return the cursor to the original appearance; again, that's too disruptive. I simply want to press a hotkey to temporarily show the location of the mouse pointer (without having to move the mouse).

Hoping someone can relate ... and can offer a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I'm unaware of any free options aside from wiggling the mouse, but check out https://apps.apple.com/us/app/simple-mouse-locator/id946676425?mt=12 - it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Or another from coderace: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mypoint-light-s/id518658487?ls=1

Comment: Thanks. The developers of Simple Mouse Locator told me their product does exactly what I'm looking for; however, they also informed me that it is not yet compatible with Big Sur.